# Ads are not showing in our new apk while they are showed on the current app on the store

Tags: android, admob

Our problem is a bit weird... Let me explain it from the beginning.

We try to publish a first app several weeks earlier, Play Store did not accept it so we had to completly create a new app on Admob and on the Developer Console. This app is now working on the Store (this is the link : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appLotoTune&gl=FR).
[enter image description here][1]
Let's call app not approved App1 and the app approved App2.

So, we used Admob ads ids of App1 in App2. It's working perfectly. But we've added the app2 in Admob and we've created ads for App2.

Now, we would like to make some changes for the app but ads are not working anymore, we've tried app1 ads ids, app2 ads ids and we even created a second admob account but nothing is working.

Strangely, we've tried test ads and they are working.

So, we conclude it was not about code but maybe about Admob.

All the ads have been created more than 2 days ago. So it's not about waiting for ads to work.

If anyone has any ideas about the source of our problem, let us know !

Have a nice day !

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ocz5R.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPvWq.png

Comment: Sometimes it is delayed in real Ad to show. So I think you need to wait and see.

Comment: Please insert your code in post instead of bitmaps, this will help people with similar problems finding your question. Also do some cleanup such as actually entering image description (if any image left after code insertion)

Comment: Actually, I don't think it's about delay cause we've been trying since more than 3 days...